# How can I learn to type on a JIS keyboard?

Tags: discussion, learning

I have a Macbook with a Japanese keyboard for the purpose of assisting my learning the language. I would like to learn to type using a JIS keyboard without using the phonetic IME. Are there any resources to help learning to type?

Comment: About 20 years ago, I was involved in testing some software. It was sufficiently low level that it needed testing with both the romaji input and direct kana input. We had to hire a tester who was suffiently proficient at using it as none of the Japanese staff had ever used that input mode. In over 20 years in Japan, I have never seen or heard of any Japanese person using it. (The input method used on mobile phones is pretty well universally used on non smart phones and supported on iOS too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

かな入力 (one key = one kana), is actually not that popular among native speakers - although supposedly it is faster once you're used to it.  There have been a few questions about it on kotonoha.cc - the impression I get is that it's considered difficult and ローマ字入力 is more convenient for some situations (can't type urls or html code in kana), so if you only learn one it will normally be ローマ字入力.

However, if you want a go, you can find online typing games etc. just by googling something like:
かな入力 練習