# What questions are on-topic for JL&U?

Tags: discussion, scope

I want to ask a question on Japanese Language and Usage about X. Is it on topic?

Comment: This is a work in progress to try to deal with http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/694/faq-does-not-describe-what-is-in-or-out-of-scope

Comment: possible duplicate of [What questions are not allowed on Japanese Language and Usage?](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-and-usage)

Comment: Yeah... sorry for sorta stealing all of this, but I liked the format of your "what are some good attributes of questions?" meta post, and thought it would work better for this type of FAQ entry. I don't really see a reason to 'close' this question, as there's nothing bad about it... but perhaps detag 'faq-proposed'?

Comment: In current form, this question is entirely superceded by [What questions are not allowed on Japanese Language and Usage?](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/796) and [How should I format my questions on JLU?](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/806), both of which are faqs.

Comment: @jkerian you need to do `[meta-tag:faq]`, like this [meta-tag:faq].

Comment: ahh thanks... was wondering how to do that

Comment: @jkerian It'd probably be best to close this as a duplicate of (both) of those then.  You'd need one person to vote for each topic for them to show up in the final list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been superseded by [What questions are not allowed on Japanese Language SE?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/796/91) and [How should I format my questions on Japanese Language SE?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/806/91) , which are both tagged as [faq](/questions/tagged/faq).

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: opinions differ somewhat about what questions should or shouldn't be allowed. Also, this answer is a work in progress - I may have missed a few meta posts or examples of closed questions.

Some questions are regarded as off-topic for Japanese Language and Usage, but are permitted on meta: [Allow limited resource questions in meta?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32/allow-limited-resource-questions-in-meta) . This happens especially with questions on [input-methods](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/input-methods) how to type Japanese. An example of such a question is [How can I learn to type on a JIS keyboard?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/543/how-can-i-learn-to-type-on-a-jis-keyboard)

Questions that are pure [translation](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) requests where no effort has been made may be closed: [What is a ダンディー?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2176/what-is-a-%E3%83%80%E3%83%B3%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%BC)

Questions that are purely about Japanese [culture](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/culture) are off-topic: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2511/is-it-a-rumor-that-eating-really-loudly-is-considered-polite

Questions that might summon Cthulhu are off-topic: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/374/regex-match-sentences-except-sentences-contained-in-「」

For further information, browse the questions on meta tagged [scope](/questions/tagged/scope), [allowed-questions](/questions/tagged/allowed-questions) and [target-audience](/questions/tagged/target-audience), or browse the closed questions on JL&U by doing a search for `closed:1`.

Comment: The acceptability of 'resources' question is anything but settled. Considering 1) such questions were specifically excluded by the proposal itself. 2) they are *by definition* ill-fitted for SE's format (no one specific answer) 3) while on that page Rob states he thinks they should be allowed, he himself puts restrictions that make it very unclear what questions would and wouldn't be OK in his view.
So far, I fail to see enough to overcome the previously established consensus.

Comment: **UPDATE:** [Have at it...](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/726/scope-amendment-should-questions-about-resources-be-allowed-on-jlu)

Comment: @Dave My answer also stated that "some" (rather than "all") [tag:learning] questions are off-topic. Do you disagree with that paragraph?

Comment: if you ask me (or the initial proposal): YUP, they are even more off-topic/unanswerable. But most of what you'd call "learning" questions can just as well be seen as "resources" question (and a bad fit for SE for the same reasons). A non-resource, learning question (*not specifically tied to an item of language*) would have to be something like "What is your method to study [X]" and is a horrible question for JLU.